In need of online vocabulary databases
I've found this great resource for Austronesian languages:
https://lpan.eva.mpg.de/austronesian
I'm looking for similar websites for African and American/Amerind languages.
Specifically, I need the foreign word with English translations, not corpus data with complete sentences.
Anybody know of such sites?

Searching for "Swadesh list" will give you some cross-lingual core vocabulary. There are really a lot of them available.

Thanks. Although I don't really relish stitching stuff together myself as I've done most of my lists on my own anyway.

it's designed for macrocomparative use (so many reconstructions are controversial at best) and it doesn't really document sense shifts so I'm not sure it quite constitutes an answer, but Starostin has several databases here covering a huge range of languages: https://starlingdb.org/cgi-bin/main.cgi?flags=eygtnnl

From Starostin I've downloaded stuff in the past but didn't touch it.
Alfréd Tóth has similar comparanda scattered over the net and despite the fact he is from my coutnry, I don't see his work too strong. (Long explanation ommited here.)
Thanks in any case

Amerindian languages
